# How to Add Time with Duration dynamically in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, time

I am fetching start date and total duration from database. how to add time and duration to calculate total time in php

Below is the data iam getting dynamically.

```html
<?php 
$currenttime= date("H:i");
$starttime=$entrance->start_time;
$duration=$entrance->duration;

?>
```

```html
<?php
$finalstarttime= $starttime + $duration ;
?>
```

How to get above result. 
Time format is H:i

Comment: So what has Currenttime got to do with this

Comment: Please tell/show us the format of `start_time` and `duration`

Comment: $starttime = 16:15

Comment: $duration= 10    which is minutes

Comment: A very simple way would be, convert the start date to unix timestamp, add duration and then get back the total time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$stamp =  mktime(16, 15);
$stamp += 60 * 10;

echo date("H:i", $stamp);
```

OR

```
$stamp =  strtotime("16:15");
$stamp += 60 * 10;

echo date("H:i", $stamp);
```

Output: 16:25

Use [mktime](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_mktime.asp) or [strtotime](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp) to convert your hour and minute to timestamp (which is in seconds), convert your duration in second `10 min * 60` add both of them.

Now get back the final time using [date](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp) function

Answer (score 3):

Using the class [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) it would be something like this:

```
<?php

$starttime = "16:15";
$duration= "10";

$finalstarttime = (DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", $starttime))->add(new DateInterval("PT".$duration."M"));

echo $finalstarttime->format("H:i"); // 16:25
```

where

```
DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", $starttime)
```

creates a [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object of the given time-string,

```
new DateInterval("PT".$duration."M")
```

creates a [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) (in Minutes)

which is added to the starttime via [DateTime::add()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)